# H5py: reopening file in write mode deletes previous data

Tags: python, file, hdf5, h5py

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

f = h5py.File('test','w')
f.create_dataset('key1', data = np.array([1,2,3]))
f.create_dataset('key2', data = np.array([4,5,6]))
f.close()
```

creates the file named test and writes two arrays under key1 and key2 respectively.

However, closing the file object and reopening the file deletes the data previously stored.

```
f = h5py.File('test','w')
f.create_dataset('key1', data = np.array([1,2,3]))
f.close()
f = h5py.File('test','w')
f.create_dataset('key2', data = np.array([4,5,6]))
f.close()
```

In this case only `[4,5,6]` is stored under the key `key2`.

How to reopen the file and write new data without deleting the old data which is already stored?

Comment: Have you tried append mode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Quick answer

Change `h5py.File('test','w')` to `h5py.File('test','a')` (or `h5py.File('test')`, which defaults to the latter).

## Why

When you instantiate a `h5py.File` object, you have to specify a `mode` as the second parameter. This must be one of the following:

- `r`   Readonly, file must exist
- `r+`  Read/write, file must exist
- `w`   Create file, truncate if exists
- `w-` or `x`   Create file, fail if exists
- `a`   Read/write if exists, create otherwise (default)

Using `a` is a quick fix, but risky if your program doesn't always know whether the file already exists. You can achieve any desired behavior in a less ambiguous way by using the other modes along with file checking.